# an alternative for HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(DataContextKey) in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'd like to upgrade some codes to `ASP.NET Core 2`.
I know that the `HttpContext.Current` is removed from `ASP.NET Core 2` and must use `IHttpContextAccessor`.

But I don't know how should I alternate this code:

> HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(DataContextKey)

How can I do it?

The complete code:

```
namespace Jahan.Infrastructure.DataAccess.DataContextStorage
{
    public class HttpDataContextStorageContainer<T> : IDataContextStorageContainer<T> where T : class
    {
        private const string DataContextKey = "DataContext";

        public T GetDataContext()
        {
            T objectContext = null;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(DataContextKey))
            {
                objectContext = (T)HttpContext.Current.Items[DataContextKey];
            }
            return objectContext;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(DataContextKey))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items[DataContextKey] = null;
            }
        }

        public void Store(T objectContext)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(DataContextKey))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items[DataContextKey] = objectContext;
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(DataContextKey, objectContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jahan, I'm finally doing the same. Your code looks exactly like mine. Maybe we are using the same source? If so, I'd appreciate if you can share the generic source code to help my conversion. May I ask the source of this source code you have? Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inject `IHttpContextAccessor` and access the current `HttpContext` via that. The rest should be simple enough to refactor.

For example.

```
public class HttpDataContextStorageContainer<T> : IDataContextStorageContainer<T> where T : class {
    private const string DataContextKey = "DataContext";
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

    public HttpDataContextStorageContainer(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }

    public T GetDataContext() {
        var current = accessor.HttpContext;
        T objectContext = null;
        if (current.Items.ContainsKey(DataContextKey)) {
            objectContext = (T)current.Items[DataContextKey];
        }
        return objectContext;
    }

    public void Clear() {
        var current = accessor.HttpContext;
        if (current.Items.ContainsKey(DataContextKey)) {
            current.Items[DataContextKey] = null;
        }
    }

    public void Store(T objectContext) {
        var current = accessor.HttpContext;
        if (current.Items.ContainsKey(DataContextKey)) {
            current.Items[DataContextKey] = objectContext;
        } else {
            current.Items.Add(DataContextKey, objectContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Just make sure that `IHttpContextAccessor` and its implementation is registered with the services container. It is not added by default any more.

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```